# disable/enable jquery DOM caching

Tags: jquery

I have a site where one div is using a third party (jstree) which relies on JQuery where as the rest of the site does not.

I want to have JQuery do it's DOM caching only on that div for performance reasons (speed, memory). Is that possible ?

Maybe if there is a way to enable/disable jquery dom caching I can enable it on that div focus and disable it when it's blured ?

Comment: If you are looking to eliminate jQuery's load time, you can use deferred loading for jQuery

Comment: no I want to disable/enable jquery DOM caching while my code is running